# Why is IIS appending localhost/default.aspx to the URL?

Tags: iis, url

This is a very strange problem.  We have a Windows 7 machine.  We have one web site set up and it works fine.  We added a second web site.  It is a very simple web site.  There is only one file - test.html.  Then we set up both sites to use host headers.  Then we added entries in our HOSTS file that matches both of those and points back to 127.0.0.1.  The first web site still works fine.  However when we open up a browser and enter the following:

http://site-2/test.html

Immediately the browser changes to

http://site-2/localhost/default.aspx/localhost/default.aspx/localhost/default.aspx/localhost/default.aspx...

And it keeps repeating and repeating and I get an error about the length of the URL being too long.  Does anyone have any idea why this would be happening?  It is very strange and I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Thanks,
Corey

Comment: Will it successfully serve up any other type of file (css/js/jpg) from site-2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured it out.  For some unknown reason the brand new second site that we created had an HTTP redirect set up to go to localhost/default.aspx.  I don't know why it was set up that way by default when we created a brand new site but it was.